# Problet to Nested StimulSoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

Field UserName has value in StimulSoft but list OrderLogViewModels nothing any value.. how do i get it?

```
public class OrderLogsViewModel
{
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  public List<ViewModel.LogsViewModel> OrderLogViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where are you initializing OrderLogsViewModel and how are you checking the values

Comment: OrderLogViewModels has values and correctly transmits Stimulus

But the problem is OrderLogViewModels in Stimul, I can't get the nested listing in Business Object

Answer (score 0):

If you use mrt file you can define new **Child Of Business Object**;

1. Add a business object with **Model** name and add **Id, UserName** column to it;
2. Right click on Model and select **New Business Object** (Child Of Business Object);
   [image: New Child Of Business Object]
3. Select Child Of Business Object and then name it what you want like **OrderLogViewModels** and then add your **LogsViewModel class properties** to it;
   [image: Child Of Business Object]
   [image: New Columns]
4. Set your data band's **Data Source** to **OrderLogViewModels** and use it in your Text component like **Model.OrderLogViewModels.OrderId** or **Model.OrderLogViewModels.Log**;
   [image: Data Source]
   [image: Data Band And Texts]